# Are there any issues connecting Neutral and Live at once to the supply line?

Tags: wiring, neutral

A normal plug point has the wiring structure of the normal cct diagram I've drawn below. I'm thinking about plugging a device into the outlet in a permanent way and keep the switch closed and control it using a switch at a separate place. My problem is will there be any electrical sparks or anything if I connect the live and neutral to the supply line at once?

[image: CCT Diagram]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your circuit diagram looks perfectly safe.

A two pole isolator is often used where the need is to *make a circuit safe to work on*, not simply to *turn off the power*.

Earth should not be switched, your diagram looks correct.

**Disclaimers**  As always, check the law and codes in your country. You might need to have a professional certify it safe. There will be rules about the type of wire, termination, labelling etc. The body of the 2-pole switch should also be earthed, and the earth cable should run in the conduit between them, not taking a short cut. The power should run through the switch, not there-and-back. You are probably not allowed to fasten the cord of a portable device to the wall in any way, or run it under a carpet or floor.  You're probably not allowed to mount a hand tool in a permanent way. I can't tell you that *your system* is safe, but the electrical concept is not dangerous.

Comment: I'm planning on using this to my PC. I have to use 3 plug points to plug in the monitor, system tower and router. Each time I have to go there and plug them and switch on. So I'm thinking about having them moved into a nearer location with 3 switches and keep the wall socket plugged in all the time. So would that be safe? :(

Comment: Why do you want to unplug them, or use a 2-pole switch? Why not just use a switched power strip?

Comment: [link]http://i01.i.aliimg.com/photo/v0/60146420673/2Gang_1Way_Wall_Switch_Button_Panel_Switch.jpg_220x220.jpg[link] I want to use this switch instead. It's kinda cool :D

Answer (score 0):

The brief answer is that it will probably be OK as shown, but removing Earth from the connections is problematic especially if whatever you are connecting has metal parts that could come into contact with a person. Earth is a safety feature in case live comes loose inside.

Comment: But the box that the extra switch is in should be earthed, in case something comes loose inside there.